# Keras: Huge loss after adding class weights

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I'm working on a LSTM model in Keras with the goal of next word prediction utilizing BERT word vectors as a part of my inputs for the model.

This is a multi-class categorical problem, and I've done some weird steps to simplify English into clusters of words using BERT and stop-words and k-means, and for my initial practice model I'm using 144 target categories. I plan to up that to about 1000 after working out some kinks.

Here's the architecture of my Keras model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(SENTENCE_LENGTH, COM_WORDS), dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(COM_WORDS))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))


optimizer = Adam(lr=lr)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.05, batch_size=128, epochs=epochs)
```

My loss starts arounds around 6 and goes down, which isn't unusual as far as I know. I then tried to incorporate class weights, since the model was over-predicting common words like 'the', which is expected. so I used this code to make the weights:

```
max_count = 0
for word in range(COM_WORDS):
    if Ys.count(word) > max_count:
        max_count = Ys.count(word)

class_weights = {}
for word in range(COM_WORDS):
    class_weights[word] = (max_count - Ys.count(word) + 1)
```

So my most common y-input would have a value of 1 in the dictionary, and an y-input that is only represented once would be weighted at the count of the most common y-input: around 1 million in this case. Then I added it to my fit() and restarted the model.

When I run my model with the weights, i get insanely high loss (this is just a batch of 100,000 of all my inputs being run):
Epoch 1/3
950000/950000 [==============================] - 160s 168us/step - loss: 3014409.5359 - acc: 0.1261 - val_loss: 2808283.0898 - val_acc: 0.1604

The accuracy is fine though! Not too different than when I didn't use weights.

MY QUESTION(s):
Does this high loss matter? Is it just a reflection of my huge weight numbers, or is it indicating something sinister? Are loss numbers relative?

Side question: Should I use a better method to weight my inputs?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, adjusting class weights like that will blow your loss value way out of proportion. But it's a relative thing. Your loss can be `10^1000` and still converge to a usable model. I'm not sure if that class-weight method is standard but it looks sensible and should work as it adjusts less frequent words to be more important to the model

Comment: @BrianJoseph Thanks!